# Are there any premade Relay to Mains boards?

Tags: relay, mains

I'm looking for a prebuilt, safe mains relay assembly. I have relays, but I'm not about to cut up a lamp cord and solder it to the little nubbins.

I think there should be something out there that is has like IEC in (female) on one side and a normal AC socket on the other and somewhere to mount a relay in between.

What do people use?  I just want to hook a lamp to a microcontroller.

This post is about the physical connections, not schematics.

Answer (score 2):

Ready-made boards designed to control mains devices from microcontrollers or personal computers do exist. You'll generally find these when looking for home automation accessories.

For example, [here is a 4-relay board](http://denkovi.com/product/44/usb-four-4-relay-output-module-board-for-home-automation.html) designed to work with a computer via USB (and, by extension, other networked devices such as smart phones).

For microcontrollers and development kits like Arduino, there are plans and designs to be found on the internet, but I don't know of any that are commercially available.

For developing your own, you might want to see a related question here:

- [Simple and safe solution to control a power plug with Arduino or PC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33312/2028)